# How to construct an auxiliary array for casting "int[][][]" to "int***"?

Tags: c++

I am a newbie in C++ and it is only for learning purposes.

I just understood how to  cast `int input [][]` to `int** output` with an auxiliary `int* aux []` as follows.

```
int TwoD()
{
    int input[][3] = { {1,2,3},{4,5,6} };

    int* aux[2];

    aux[0] = input[0];// array of int ---> pointer to int
    aux[1] = input[1];// array of int ---> pointer to int

    int** output = aux;// array of int* ---> pointer to int*

    for (int i = 0; i < 2; i++)
        for (int j = 0; j < 3; j++)
            cout << output[i][j] << endl;
}
```

Now I want to extend it to 3D as follows.

```
void ThreeD()
{
    int input[2][3][4] =
    {
        {
            {1,2,3,4},
            {5,6,7,8},
            {9,10,11,12}
        },
        {
            {13,14,15,16},
            {17,18,19,20},
            {21,22,23,24}
        }
    };

    //int(*output)[3][4] = input;

    int** aux[2];
    aux[0][0] = input[0][0];
    aux[0][1] = input[0][1];
    aux[0][2] = input[0][2];
    aux[1][0] = input[1][0];
    aux[1][1] = input[1][1];
    aux[1][2] = input[1][2];

    int*** output = aux;

    for (int i = 0; i < 2; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < 3; j++)
        {
            for (int k = 0; k < 4; k++)
                cout << output[i][j][k] << " ";
            cout << endl;
        }
        cout << endl;
    }
}
```

It compiles but only produce a blank screen. What is the correct auxiliary `aux` and how to initialize it?

Comment: Since `aux` doesn't point to anything, `aux[0]` is undefined behavior.

Comment: Why are you interested in converting your array to a `int***`?

Comment: `int***` is such obvious code smell, a sign of bad code, that it's become a joke. It makes you a [three star programmer](http://wiki.c2.com/?ThreeStarProgrammer).

Comment: Are there awards for the most consecutive \*'s in a program? Otherwise, what's int*** supposed to do?

Comment: @FrançoisAndrieux: It is just for learning purposes. I am looking for the pattern.

Comment: Why are you learning C if you intend to learn C++? The `[ ]` stuff has so much exceptions it should be much later on the program

Comment: jokes aside, here's a simple app to help you understand some gibberish: https://cdecl.org/. see, type of aux is now: "array 2 of pointer to pointer to int" so the way you populate it is wrong, for example

Comment: [Arrays decay to pointers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1461432/what-is-array-decaying). Multi-dimensional arrays decay to pointers to arrays, not pointers to pointers. In general, arrays are annoying to pass around. It's best to not use them. Prefer library containers like `std::vector` and `std::array`.

Comment: @user4581301: what type should the `aux` be? Give me a hint.

Comment: `std::vector<std::vector<std::vector<int>>>`, or if the size for each dimension is fixed, use `std::array<std::array<std::array<int, X>, Y>, Z>`

Comment: The accepted answer is what I am looking for. Now I am ready to proceed to become a C++ master. :-)

Comment: @GodMustBeCrazy Heh. I resisted the urge to state that by the time I could make a proper answer explaining what was going on and how to avoid it, someone would have posted one much more succinct. Glad to see I was right.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need another layer of pointers.

```
int input[2][3][4] =
{
   {
      {1,2,3,4},
      {5,6,7,8},
      {9,10,11,12}
   },
   {
      {13,14,15,16},
      {17,18,19,20},
      {21,22,23,24}
   }
};

int* aux1[2][3] =
{
   { input[0][0], input[0][1], input[0][2] },
   { input[1][0], input[1][1], input[1][2] },
};

int** aux2[2] = {aux1[0], aux1[1]};

int*** output = aux2;
```

Comment: I love your explanation. It is very clear and direct to the problem.

Comment: @GodMustBeCrazy, glad to hear it was useful :)

Comment: Sorry, I have a question about function pointer. If we pass a callback `bool isOdd (int x){return x%2==1;}` as an argument of another function with a signature `PrintList(bool (*f)(int),....other parameters...)`, which is the correct invocation ?`PrintList(isOdd,....);` or `PrintList(&isOdd,...);`?

Comment: @GodMustBeCrazy, both are correct. Non-member functions are special in that regard.